# Eclipse WSDL generator (from java class)?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wsdl

I want to generate WSDL compliant with Java classes. At this phase I don't want to put it online, just have the wsdl (in order to discuss it with someone else) and validate the generated file.

I'm using Eclipse, so I would prefer any solution that's already integrated with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From eclipse in the java perspective:

1. Right click on the Java class you want to use as your service implementation
2. Select Web Services -> Create Web Service
3. Web service type should be "Botton up Java bean Web Service"

This will generate a WSDL file for you.

Comment: I don't have that option. Which plugin did you install? I'm using Eclipse Indigo

Comment: I am using Indigo as well.  I don't have any special plugins installed.  Maybe you need the Enterprise Edition of Eclipse?

Comment: Under Help -> About Eclipse it says I am using "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers".  So I am guessing your aren't using the EE version of Eclipse.

Comment: Looks like you need the Web Tools Project (WTP): http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

Comment: I already installed it but that option forces me to have a server (and I was in a rush to make the files). I've used wsgen.exe (under jdk bin folder) and it worked well

Comment: I had the same problem, but I found out that some service (I immediately forgot the name of the service) needed installing/activating, but this was painless. I had to add a new perspective and bring up Java EE. This wasn't shown at first, so I checked "show all" at the bottom of the perspectives window, then java ee appeared, and when I selected it, it said something needed activation, and low and behold, "Web Services" appeared in the context menu

Answer (score 3):

Also you can publish the service at localhost with any server (Tomcat, for instance) and then with your browser in the address bar write

```
http://localhost:<server_port>/path/to/your/service?wsdl
```

If the service is correctly configured, you should see the generated wsdl. Then you can copy/paste in any text editor and save it as `myService.wsdl`.

Hope that helps