# Java SOAP WebService - How to accept single input parameter

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I'm developing a SOAP based Webservice API which would be used by a third party system. WSDL file and endpoint URL would be shared with them and they invoke my Web service by passing an input parameter and get the response back

So far, I have created the Web Service API including WSDL, Services Classes, Helper Classes, DAO, Ibatis) and tested using SOAP UI by passing the input parameter, the request hits the databse and returning the response fine. Attached the WSDL file and SOAP request and response.

I got two questions,

1. The 3rd Party system is asking for an API documentation and SOAP Envelope. What should I give?
2. The 3rd party system has to invoke my service by passing the input parameter sQuoteRef. How would they usually do it? I'm not concerned about the client code here but how would the request from 3rd party look like and what changes I should make in my WSDL or Java classes to receive the input parameter and pass on to my service class?

Any inputs would be helpful in completing my task. Many Thanks!

WSDL File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions name="EmpService" targetNamespace="http://emp.provider.integration.gi.sample.ie/EmpService/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://Emp.provider.integration.gi.sample.ie/EmpService/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://Emp.provider.integration.gi.sample.ie/EmpService/">

          <xsd:element name="EmpRequestVO">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="sQuoteRef" type="xsd:string"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="EmpResponseVO">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="sQuoteStatus" type="xsd:string"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
      </wsdl:types>

      <wsdl:message name="GetEmpTransactionSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:EmpRequestVO" name="parameters"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="GetEmpTransactionSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:EmpResponseVO" name="parameters"/>
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:portType name="EmpServiceSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="getEmpTransaction">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:GetEmpTransactionSoapIn"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:GetEmpTransactionSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>

      <wsdl:binding name="EmpServiceSoap" type="tns:EmpServiceSoap">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getEmpTransaction">
          <soap:operation soapAction="getEmpTransaction" style="document"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>

      <wsdl:service name="PLUSEmpServices">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:EmpServiceSoap" name="EmpServiceSOAP">
          <soap:address location="http://localhost:9080/WebServices/services/EmpServiceSOAP"/>
        </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

End Point URL
http://localhost:9080/PLUSEmpServices/services/EmpServiceSOAP

```
SOAP REQUEST in SOAP UI

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rtw="http://emp.provider.integration.gi.sample.ie/EmpService/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rtw:EmpRequestVO>
         <sQuoteRef>12123118</sQuoteRef>
      </rtw:EmpRequestVO>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

SOAP RESPONSE in SOAP UI
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <p900:EmpResponseVO xmlns:p900="http://emp.provider.integration.gi.sample.ie/EmpService/">
         <sQuoteStatus>Active</sQuoteStatus>
      </p900:EmpResponseVO>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The 3rd Party system is asking for an API documentation and SOAP Envelope. What should I give?

To start APIs integration with external parties, your clients require a technical API document that will be a reference to complete APIs integration and a base for any technical communication between the teams. The technical document may includes the following details:

1. Brief description for different available web-services APIs and their requirements.
2. APIs communications flow. This will be useful in case the clients need to call more than one services in specific sequence. Including flow diagram will be possible option to explain the system flow.
3. Test environment details like WSDL URL and access credentials like username, password, agent code, etc.
4. Detailed description for all fields needed to send a valid request to the server. Fields details may include the following:

   a.    Filed name.

   b.    Description.

   c.    Data Type.

   d.    Max length.

   e.    Mandatory, Optional or Conditional.

   f.    Possible values if any.
5. All possible response codes a long with their description sent by server API to client API which indicates the successful or failure of transaction process(s). For example (0000 means Success, E001 means validation error, E002 system error, 9999 unknown error, etc.).

Note: Response codes should cover various rejection cases.

6. Security Section that explain how the data is exchange securely between client and server application.

   a.    Mention additional Encryption mechanism for part or all request data if any.

   b.    Communication type with the client wither it is over VPN or accessed public 
   over https URL. Note the URL you mentioned in your question is deployed in your local machine and it will not be available publicly.
7. Sample SOAP request(s) and response(s) xml format for all available API’s web methods.
8. Mention any additional rules or constrains on APIs connectivity.

> The 3rd party system has to invoke my service by passing the input parameter sQuoteRef. How would they usually do it? I'm not concerned about the client code here but how would the request from 3rd party look like and what changes I should make in my WSDL or Java classes to receive the input parameter and pass on to my service class?

If I understand you correctly your are asking how should I change WSDL or Java classes to accept client request correctly ? Usually the server side API has the upper hand in XML format need to be exchanged and in your case it should be mentioned in WSDL. So the client will create a valid request as per definition mentioned in server WSDL URL.

Further reading that my be useful on how to generate WSDL from Java classes:

[Eclipse WSDL generator (from java class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716771/eclipse-wsdl-generator-from-java-class)

[SOAP fault handling in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043830/soap-fault-handling-in-java/29225707#29225707)

Comment: Hi Salman, Thanks for your time in answering my question. Your answer is very clear on the API documentation side. Now my question is, The WSDL file I have accepts the request from SOAP UI and returns the response as expected. How would the client request look like? Possibly a query string? If so what changes I should make to the WSDL or Java classes to accept the client request along with the input param and pass back the response.

Comment: @user2381118 You are building the server side API and you exposed itto other clients using WSDL. WSDL define how the request will look like from the client and that what you experience with SoapUI. When you used SoapUI, you were using it as a client for the server API you built and SoapUI built XML request based on the given WSDL. Similarly, any other clients need to use the WSDL to format their requests. You do not need to change your WSDL to accept different client request, actually it is the other way back; the client need to make sure to build their request in away that match with the WSDL

Comment: Thanks Salman. So I guess I don't need to worry and have to ask the client system to build their request to match the WSDL.

Comment: Just wondering, Do you know how to implement WS Security? I have to validate the client with a username/password to confirm their Authenticity. Thanks in advance.